# Textbox issue when writing in Hebrew language

Tags: excel, vba

Textbox object in VBA don't set properly to Hebrew language . That object become messy with number and Hebrew Letters probably because Hebrew is written from right to left. any one know how to set it properly?

[image: this how it set properly]

[image: this is the mess object]

Comment: There is no question asked?

Comment: hahah thanks i fix it